# Dynamically Cast a String to JSONDecoder Decodable.Protocol Type

Tags: swift, codable, jsondecoder

I have some enum values that I would like to cast to a JSONDecoder Decodable.Protocol type
that can be used in the `decode` method.

Each of the Attributes enums Correspond to a `Codable` class.

```
enum Attributes : String {
    case Shapes = "GetShapes"
    case Color  = "GetColors"
    case Size   = "GetSizes"
}
```

Instead of having a bunch of switch statements I thought I could dynamically cast the *enum* to the correct Protocol and save myself a lot of code.

For example

```
let results = try? JSONDecoder().decode(GetShapes.self, from: jsonData)
```

Notice that `GetShapes.self`, corresponds to an *Attributes* enum's value.

So I tried using `NSProtocolFromString` but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
if let protoRef = NSProtocolFromString(anAttribute.rawValue) {
    if let results = try? JSONDecoder().decode(protoRef, from: jsonData) {
        //Do something
}
```

Being able to cast the string to the protocol would save me a lot of work.

---

**Hopefully this clarifies:**

Basically, take a string "GetShapes", use some MagicMethod() so it spits out

`GetShapes.self` that satisfies the ***type*** parameter of the `JSONDecoder().decode(type: Decodable.Protocol, from: Data)`

Some method like this:

```
func magicMethod(_ string: String) -> Decodable.Protocol {

}
```

**Is this possible with Swift 4?**

Comment: You can only decode **types** not single properties or cases. And all `NS...FromString` methods are Objective-C related API which don't work with the native Swift counterparts.

Comment: What would you recommend in this case? I don't want to have to create a switch statement for every enum.

Comment: I don't know what you are looking for. In case of the enum your dictionary can contain `["foo": "GetShapes"]`, `["foo": "GetColors"]` or `["foo": "GetSizes"]` and if `Attributes` conforms to `Decodable` you can decode `let foo = try container.decode(Attributes.self, forKey: .foo)`

Comment: @vadian I edited my question, hopefully it will make sense now.

Comment: I'm still confused after your clarification, but I don't think your magic method is the answer. Do you have a class or a struct that is of type `GetShapes`, and you've created an enum with a list of your types? What type do you expect `results` to be after the above code executes?